# Как сделать такой ефект следащего кружочка

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Увидел на одном сайте такой эффект. Суть в том, что внутри как бы два кружочка двигаются в зависимости от позиции курсора и словно летают по тексту. Очень хотел бы узнать, как сделать такой же эффект в React и что используется для создания такого эффекта.

В идеале яб хотел повторить такой же ефект но не знаю каким образом

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю вы ищете css свойство mix-blend-mode. Из документации:

> Определяет режим наложения исходного цвета на фоновый цвет или фоновое изображение.

Т.е. добавить такой эффект можно следующим способом:

1. Создать блок
2. Привязать перемещение блока к перемещению мыши
3. Добавить блоку стиль `mix-blend-mode: hue;`

Пример: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/circle-in-words-qc57xg

У свойства много значений, выберите которое вам подходит